# Angular 4 looping through object of objects

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to display all the keys in json format to angular 4 template but I get object object

here what I am doing:

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of mainData.categories; index as i">
      <p>
        {{ cat.items}}
      </p> 
</div>
```

my json data that I am looping through

```
"main": [
      {
        "mainText": "demo1",
        "text": "abc",
        "keyVal": "",
        "index": "1",
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "1.1",
            "text": "lorem ipsum",
            "keyVal": "",
            "index": "1.1",
            "items": {
              "first": true,
              "second": true,
              "third": true,
              "forth": true,
            }
```

and my ts file

```
showData() {
    this.myform.getData().subscribe(
      info => {
        if (info) {
         this.mainData = info[0].main[0];
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I want to display all items keys not the values. for example "first,second,third,forth"
if I do {{cat.items.first}} then it display the value only which is true. but I want to loop all the items and their keys only.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this really easy, you could use the [json pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) - however this will also display the values:

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of mainData.categories; index as i">
      <p>
        {{ cat.items | json}}
      </p> 
</div>
```

Output will be your json data (formatted) as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to iterate over keys of an object. To use in the template, you first need do assign it to a component variable, like:

```
@Component({
  selector: ...,
  template: ...
})

export class YourComponent {
   objectKeys = Object.keys;
   constructor(){}
}
```

Then use it in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of mainData.categories">
  <p *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(cat.items)">
    {{ key }}
  </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use Object.keys(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE) this method return all the keys of an object